# Receiver application not getting closed when user click cast button to disconnect in android sender app

Tags: android, chromecast

I've a custom receiver which works fine except one problem that is when user clicks **"STOP CASTING"** button on android sender application.

I've implemented Cast SDK v3.

The sender seems to be disconnected because next time when cast button is clicked it asks for the chromecast device to connect.

The problem is that the receiver doesn't stop playing video on TV, as if it has no idea about the sender been disconnected.

The documentation https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#app_flow says that

- When the user clicks on the Cast button to disconnect from the Cast
  device, the framework will disconnect the sender app from the
  receiver.

But this doesn't seem to work in my case.

Can anyone tell me what to do or what the solution might be for this issue?

Comment: How are you stopping the service? What code methods are you using?

Comment: I figured that problem by adding a method to my custom receiver that checks number of senders connected when a sender disconnects and if senders are equal to zero, then it calls the close method of receiver.

Comment: good thing you were able to solve it, you can share your code to the community if you want so it helps others as well :D

Comment: Should I post it as an answer? :D

Comment: yeah sure, for the benefit of others :D

Comment: @noogui Was that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the following method to my custom receiver:

```
window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
        castReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected = function(event) {
    console.log('Received Sender Disconnected event: ' + event.data);
    if (window.castReceiverManager.getSenders().length == 0) {
           window.close();
    }
};
```